# Ajax Status Pending On Multiple Requests

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to create a `jQuery` Progress Listener.

I have a button which on click executes a PHP script, which runs through a bunch of functions and foreach loops and it takes a while to load.

I want to get a response on each loop using the  `XMLHttpRequest()`. I am using [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih1i56YOgmM) as a reference. But the scripts are not working well.

When I opened The Chrome Developer Tools on the Network Tab, the request `checkprogress.php` is sent but the response is "pending" until the scripts finish the load, and then it responds with 100% all of a sudden .

Below is the code for each file

**checkprogress.php**

```
<?php

$file = "progress.txt";
$data = file_get_contents($file);
echo $data;
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container{
        width: 300px;
        height: 20px;
        border: solid thin #aaa;
    }
    #progress{
        background-color: lightblue;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        color: grey;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div id="container"><div id="progress">0%</div></div>
<button id="start" onclick="begin(event)">Start</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var prog = document.getElementById('progress');
    var button = document.getElementById('start');

    function begin(event){

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        xhr.open("POST", "script.php", true);
        
        xhr.onload = function(){
            
            if(xhr.status === 200){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                clearInterval(timer);
            }

        }
        
        timer = setInterval(checkProgress, 100);
        xhr.send();
    }

    function checkProgress(event){

        xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        xhr2.open("POST", "checkprogress.php", true);
        
        xhr2.onload = function(){
            
            if(xhr2.status === 200){

                prog.style.width = xhr2.responseText + "%";
                prog.innerHTML = xhr2.responseText + "%";
            }

        }
        xhr2.send();
    }
</script>
```

**Script.php**

```
<?php

$file = "progress.txt";
for($i = 1; $i<= 10; $i++){
    
    sleep(1);
    file_put_contents($file, ($i * 10));

}
echo "done";
?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you send an AJAX request every 100ms you'll soon overwhelm your server. The previous request probably won't even complete before the next one starts, so eventually there'll be too many pending and they all block each other. Do you _really_ need to check with that frequency? The user can't even blink that fast to notice the changes. If you need to provide updates more than about once every 20 seconds or so, then use websockets or Server-Sent Events instead of AJAX, to reduce the overhead of making endless HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said above in the comment ajax sends 1 request and get only response when the php script finishes so there is no way to do that.

I was developing wordpress plugin and am new to this so the way around it as that if i am using PHP OOP and wordpress i just need to send the request through wp_ajax hook and run the methods one after another and each method must send response to ajax file and then send another request with the response data to the next method until i reach the final confirmation that's all if someone needs it I will share the code